# Set application timezone Plus one week in php

Tags: php, date, timezone

I want to set my Php application time to + 1 week .

I have set time zone below code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

so application time changed to Asia/Kolkata, but i want change application time to + 1 week

For example : when i print date using php code in application

```
date("Y/m/d")
```

i need get output Apr-12-2017.

is it feasible to change default timezone + 1 week ,

please help ,Thanks

Comment: Why would you do this..? A timezone is a timezone, you cannot *change* a timezone, but you can set your application to a specific timezone. If you want to add one week to all dates, just do that in each `date()` function, the second parameter. See http://php.net/date and http://php.net/strtotime - or learn about the DateTime class.

Comment: this is my client requirement ,  
i got manual option date + 1 week in php.but its not suitable for his requirement.

Comment: I doubt client requirements are that specific, telling you which how to implement something in PHP. The only way you could use `date()` without any extra parameter, is by changing the system clock, which you should not do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this manually. You can use the `DateTime` class to do calendar calculations. For example, to add one week, you could use code like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('05-04-2017');
$date->modify('+1 week');
```

OR, you can choose [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 week")); //1 week in the future
```

Now , either you can initialise the date variable value as globally in your project and call at required place or create it on each and every position as per required.

Comment: Extending the DateTime class, you can always add 1 week, and then you don't have to do it manually each time.

Answer (score 2):

try below one:

```
<?php
echo date("Y/m/d", strtotime("+1 week"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DateTime class, and extend it to a class of your own, that always adds 1 week to every DateTime object.

So if you do `new MyDateTime("now");` you would get the date one week from now. If you did `new MyDateTime("+1 week");`, you get two weeks (one from the argument to the constructor, one from the modification inside the class constructor).

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime {
    function __construct(string $time = "now", DateTimeZone $timezone = null) {
        parent::__construct($time, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        $this->modify("+1 week");
    }
}

$date = new MyDateTime();
echo $date->format("F jS, Y")."\n"; // +1 week from now

$one_week = new MyDateTime("+1 week");
echo $one_week ->format("F jS, Y"); // +2 weeks from now
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/52t20)

Answer (score 1):

A week is 7*24*60*60 = 604800 seconds. So, while leaving everything on the server as it should, one week from now is:

```
date('Y/m/d',time()+604800)
```

But I prefer the one Deep Kakkar also mentions:

```
date('Y/m/d',strtotime("+1 week"))
```

It just looks nicer.